# Restoring saved Angular HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my application, I am at some point making a saved state of a very large block of HTML via `$(element).contents()` (I can use `$(element).html()` if needbe). How do I convert that block back into angular if it contains complex directive information inside of it? The whole point was to avoid rebuilding the ng-repeats. But without compiling it, I lose all functionality of the angularisms within. Here's a tiny example of what the HTML string looks relatively like:

```
<div ng-controller='fruits'>
    <div class="dtable">
        <!-- ngRepeat: fruit in fruitCollection track by fruit.id -->
        <div ng-repeat="fruit in fruitCollection track by fruit.id" class="ng-scope drow selected" ng-class="fruit.selected && 'selected'">
            <div class="idx ng-scope dinline">1</div>
            <div class="name ng-scope dinline hilight">Apple</div>
            <div class="info ng-scope dinline">Red</div>
        </div>
        <!-- end ngRepeat: fruit in fruitCollection track by fruit.id -->
        <!-- ngRepeat: fruit in fruitCollection track by fruit.id -->
        <div ng-repeat="fruit in fruitCollection track by fruit.id" class="ng-scope drow" ng-class="fruit.selected && 'selected'">
            <div class="idx ng-scope dinline">2</div>
            <div class="name ng-scope dinline">Orange</div>
            <div class="info ng-scope dinline">Orange</div>
        </div>
        <!-- end ngRepeat: fruit in fruitCollection track by fruit.id -->
    </div>
    <h3>Filters</h3>
    <div class="controls dtablev">
    <!-- ngRepeat: filter in filterCollection -->
        <div class="ng-scope checked" ng-click="toggleSelection(filter)" ng-class="filter.checked && 'checked'">Red</div>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: filter in filterCollection -->
    <!-- ngRepeat: filter in filterCollection -->
        <div class="ng-scope" ng-click="toggleSelection(filter)" ng-class="filter.checked && 'checked'">Orange</div>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: filter in filterCollection -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Plainly re-inserting the HTML looks great, but you can't click on anything. I'm hoping that there's some little secret bit of `$compile` that can handle this.

Comment: How do I convert that block back into angular if it contains complex directive information inside of it? I did not get this part. Are you looking for some thing of post compiled html back in to pre compiled html and angular to compile that again

Comment: I don't think that is possible. Any binding created using `{{}}` is lost. If you add it back and do compile then it is same as just binding the model to template html. So why go through all this.

Comment: rather than recreating the html block.. plz store the html as a template and associated data as javascript model and re render it whenever needed...

Answer (score 0):

After adding the HTML back on to the page you should use the [$compile](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile) service on the root element.

```
$compile(element)($scope);
```